# O método __destruct tem utilidade?

Tags: php, método

Eu li sobre o método `__destruct` nestes dois links:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240230/is-the-destruct-method-necessary-for-php

E ainda não achei a utilidade do método `__destruct`, ainda mais que segundo o @user166390, (o usuário que respondeu a questão do 2º link) disse:

> .."A destructor has nothing directly to do with releasing memory" (...Um destrutor não tem haver com liberar memória diretamente...

Segundo ele, teria um outro propósito que não entendi muito bem. Alguém poderia me dar uma explicação prática do uso do `__destructor`? E um exemplo em que o `__destructor` seja necessário?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tem sim, mas primeiro você tem que entender em que momentos ele é executado.

O conceito é similar ao de outras linguagens como o *C++*, o `__destruct` é sempre disparado quando a referencia de uma "classe chamada" é "destruída", por exemplo:

```
$test = new MinhaClasse();
$test = null; //A partir daqui o __destruct provavelmente será chamado (ou no fim do script)
```

Se não houver nada assim no script e a variável for acessível por outros escopos, então o objeto vai ficar lá até ocorrer o `shutdown` do script, então o `__destruct` será disparado só quando o script já tiver sido finalizado.

### Quando usar o __destruct

Imagine que você tem uma série de variáveis na classe ou variáveis de vetores, grandes e quando a classe for destruída você quer limpar elas, então poderá usar o `__destruct`, isto ajuda na liberação de um pouco de memória (vai depender de como o [**GC**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) se comporta, não tem como controlar).

```
class Foo {
    private $bar = array();

    public function __construct() {
         $this->bar = range(1, 1000000);//Gera um grande vetor
    }

    public function __destruct() {
         $this->bar = null;//libera variável
    }
}
```

Você também pode usar isto pra desconectar de socket, ou do mysql sem precisar chamar o `mysqli_close`, por exemplo:

```
class Conexao {
    private $link = null;
    public function __construct() { //Auto-conecta
         $this->link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
         mysqli_close($this->link);//desconecta
         $this->link = null;
    }
}
```

Ao chamar assim:

```
$test = new Conexao();

//...Aqui fica todo o processo que vai usar a conexão

$test = NULL; //A partir daqui provavelmente a classe será destruída

//...Outras tarefas
```

Desta maneira você não precisará desconectar, o `__destruct` irá cuidar disto pra você.

Sobre o comentário:

> .."A destructor has nothing directly to do with releasing memory" (...Um destrutor não tem haver com liberar memória diretamente...

Ele disse "imediatamente", quer dizer que sim, "ajuda" a liberar, mas isto não ocorre imediatamente, ele é usado pra liberar "referencias" ou outras tarefas, como desconectar de um `socket`. A liberação da memória vai depender do [**GC**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) como eu citei anteriormente.

O `__destruct` não libera as referencias automaticamente, ele é um método que você mesmo deve escrever, neste método você terá que dizer como e o que deve ser liberado das "referencias internas" da classe, então as referencias estando livres o [**GC**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) vai se encarregar de tentar liberar a memória.

Comment: Obrigado. Ótimo exemplo usando o mysqli_close.

Answer (score -2):

quando a instancia não estiver sendo apontada por nenhuma variavel ela será excluida pelo coletor de lixo do PHP.

por exemplo:

```
new Conta('000.000.000-00', 'asdjauiosjdoisajd'); // será excluida pelo coletor de lixo.


$novaConta = new Conta('000.000.000-01', 'dsdsdskaa'); // não será excluida.
```

espero ter ajudado.