# Qual a "maneira correta" de usar destrutores em PHP

Tags: php, memória, método, cache

Ao procurar referencias de boas praticas em `PHP` para o gerenciamento de memória me deparei em diversos intendimentos de como usar **destrutores**.

Sei que o principal ator é o **[Garbage Collector](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.gc.php)** más este não faz parte do escopo de minha pergunta.

**Referencias:**

- o próprio [Manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php)
- entre algumas da comunidade [destaco esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105388/o-m%C3%A9todo-destruct-tem-utilidade)
- e uma [referencia externa](http://excript.com/php/destrutores-php.html)

Más minhas leituras me trouxerem dúvidas as quais não encontrei respostas sendo elas...

**Dúvidas:**

- a função **`__destruct(){}`** vazia irá remover qualquer valor associado a classe ou é necessário explicitar estes valores em seu escopo?
- após instanciar a classe por referencia e antes do encerramento do script qual a diferença entre usar **`NULL`** e **`unset()`** por exemplo:

  ```
  <?php
      $refer = new MyClass();
      $refer->hello(); // output: Hello World!

      $refer = NULL; // ou unset($refer);

      // mais blocos de código aqui...
  ```
- segundo [Manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php) a herança de clase exige que a classe "filha" explicite a chamado **`parent::__destruct()`** no destrutor... más e no caso de classes não estendidas que instanciam outra classe em seu escopo? Ao atribuir **`NULL`** ou usar **`unset()`** antes do encerramento do script forcará ambos os destrutores ou é necessário explicitar cada um? Exemplo:

  ```
  <?php
      /**
      class Core
      {
           public function __construct(){}

           public function session($start=true)
           {
               if ( !$start  ) {
                    if ( isset($_SESSION) ) {
                         session_destroy();
                         return true;
                    }
               }
               session_start();
           }

           public function language()
           {
               if ( isset($_SESSION) ) {
                    $_SESSION['language'] = 'pt-BR';
               }
           }

           public function layoutEngine()
           {
               return new HandlerUI(); // outra classe
           }

           function __destruct(){
               #
           }
      }

      class HandlerUI
      {
           function __construct()
           {
               return $this;
           }

           public function Header()
           {
               return "<head><title>Hello World</title></head>";
           }

           public function NavBar()
           {
               return "<nav>This is navbar</nav>";
           }

           public function Drawer()
           {
               return "<div class='drawer-container'></div>";
           }

           public function Footer()
           {
               return "<footer>I am Footer</footer?";
           }

           public function JavaScript()
           {
               return "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('hola que tal');</script>";
           }

           function __destruct(){
               #
           }
      }
      */

      // caso de uso:
      $app = new Core()

      $app->session();
      $app->language();

      $layout = $app->layoutEngine();

      unset($app); // ou $app = NULL;
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="<?php echo $_SESSION['language'];?>">
  <?php
      $layout->Header();
  ?>
  <body id="body">
      <!-- CONTAINER -->
      <section class="default">
          <?php
              // navbar
              $layout->Navbar();
              // drawer
              $layout->Drawer();
          ?>

          <!-- CENTRAL BLOCK -->
          <section id="central-block"></section>
          <?php
              //
              $layout->Footer();
          ?>
      </section>
      <?php
          //
          $layout->JavaScript();

          unset($layout); // ou $layout = NULL;

          // mais blocos de código aqui...
      ?>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- e a que **mais me questiono**: ao utilizar [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) ou outro cache de **bytecode** (que guarda na memória o compilado) como é tratado a fução **`__destruct()`** neste caso de uso de cache?

---

Sei que não existe uma "maneira correta" visto que isto depende de caso de uso, das necessidades do código e da abordagem em estruturá-lo más busco um entendimento qualificado do mesmo.

Desde de já grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `__destruct` serve para executar uma última ação antes do objeto deixar de existir.

Um uso que pode ser feito com ele caso você construa um framework é pôr num Controller genérico chamando uma view de mesmo nome do Controller no fim da execução. Quando outros controllers extenderem esse controller genérico todos eles terão essa funcionalidade de chamar a view adequada automaticamente no fim da execução.

Exemplo de código utilizando __construct e __destruct :

```
<?php

class Teste
{
    private $nome;

    function __construct($nome)
    {
        echo 'O objeto foi construído.<br>';
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    function saudacao()
    {
        return 'Olá ' . $this->nome . '! <br>'; 
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        echo 'O objeto não existirá mais após essa mensagem.';
    }   

}


$teste = new Teste('Lauro');

echo $teste->saudacao();


?>
```

Output gerado ao executar o script acima:

```
O objeto foi construído.
Olá Lauro!
O objeto não existirá mais após essa mensagem.
```

Observação: 
O PHP limpa todas as variáveis da memória no fim da execução do script. Então ao final do script, ao remover o objeto ele executa o destruct automaticamente. Mas se o objeto fosse destruído com unset o destruct seria chamado da mesma forma, só que antes do término da execução do script por completo.

Não há necessidade de declarar __construct ou __destruct se não for utilizá-los.

Comment: Certo más, ao utilizar `__destruct()` devo usar `unset()` em seu escopo referente a valores contidos na classe no caso de usar `unset()` na instancia antes do fim do bloco de instrução? E ao querer "liberar" um índice instanciado antes do fim do bloco de instrução em uma classe instanciada dentro de outra (não estendida) chamaria ambos os destrutores ou apenas um? E ao utilizar OPcache um destrutor teria mesmo utilidade?

Comment: Você só deve usar unset se quiser que o objeto seja destruído antes do fim da execução do script. Ao destruir um objeto é executado apenas um destrutor. Executa o destrutor do pai se não tiver sobrescrito o mesmo na classe filha. Ou seja: se tem um destrutor declarado no pai e não tem no filho, executa o do pai. Se tem um destrutor declarado no filho, executa o do filho. Se quiser executar os dois destrutores, dentro do destrutor do filho chame parent::__destruct();

Comment: Sim o foco da questão é destruir o objeto antes do fim da execução do script. Quanto a herança minha dúvida não trata de herança más sim se:  ao "forçar" o destrutor da classe "A" também forcaria o destrutor da classe "B" instanciado na classe "A" (note que não há herança entre as classes). Qual a diferença entre usar `NULL` e `unset()` para isso bem como se o uso de OPcache não neutraliza o uso de destrutores (visto que salva em memória).

Comment: "netraliza" em meu comentário anterior foi uma palavra errônea ... seria algo como: o uso de OPcache não faz o trabalho de destrutores serem em vão?

Comment: O OPcache faz os scripts ficarem salvos na memória pro php não precisar carregá-los, transformar em bytecode e executar a cada requisição. Já fica o bytecode na memória. Embora eu ainda não tenha utilizado OPcache, o funcionamento de destrutores deve permanecer o mesmo - O meu entendimento é que o bytecode do arquivo em memória não interfere nas variáveis durante a execução do script.

Comment: Referência para começar a usar OpCache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache