# Como funciona o destrutor (método "__destruct") no PHP?

Tags: php, gerenciamento-de-memória, destrutor

Uma grande diferença do PHP para o Java, que é minha linguagem nativa, é que no Java não há como destruirmos os objetos que estão em desuso, pois o `JVM` já faz isso por nós automaticamente, com o *garbage collector*. No PHP, não há um *garbage collector*, e sim os métodos destrutores, então a dúvida que fica é:

Onde e quando usar o método destrutor? O método destrutor é executado automaticamente quando a página é fechada? Se eu dar F5 na página, o objeto antigo será substituído por um novo ou os dois vão se manter na memória?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Relacionado: [**O método `__destruct` tem utilidade?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105388/3635)

Answer (score 8):

Java não tem destrutor, mas tem [finalizadores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer) e outros mecanismos mais modernos e considerados melhores. Na verdade, o destrutor foi criado mais para finalizar algo, então o termo é ruim. Não entenda este método como algo que destrói o objeto e sim que faz algo antes dele ser destruído.

Então se você entende o conceito de finalização/fechamento de recursos do Java sabe como é o [`__destruct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) do PHP. Se não entende, espero que faça apenas coisas simples.

[PHP tem GC sim](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php), só não é igual ao do Java. Alguma vez você precisou liberar memória? Dá problema se não criar destrutor na maioria dos casos?

Pra falar a verdade em 99% dos casos onde PHP é usado, nem GC nem destrutor é muito necessário. De fato tem um monte de classe que vejo por aí que estritamente falando deveria ter um construtor e não tem, mesmo assim não causa problemas porque PHP é uma linguagem de *script*.

Como o GC do PHP é determinístico ele funciona igual ao C++, então assim que o objeto não é mais necessário e não tem referências para ele, o destrutor já é chamado.

Em Java é preciso um outro mecanismo já que a liberação do objeto não é determinístico e pode até mesmo nunca ser chamado pelo GC. Ele usa o chamado `try-resource` que finaliza o objeto assim que ele não é mais necessário. E se for usado como membro de um objeto praticamente obriga a ter um finalizador no objeto que o contém. Na destruição pelo GC o finalizador só é chamado se ele não foi chamado antes.

Por causa do determinismo do PHP o destrutor é muito mais simples.

Você deve usar um destrutor sempre que tem algum recurso que precisa de uma finalização, ou seja, precisa fechar uma conexão, um arquivo, etc. Mas como eu disse, ninguém faz isso e em PHP dá na mesma em quase todos casos.

O destrutor é executado sempre que o objeto não é mais usado pelo código.

O fechamento ou recarga de uma página não interfere nisso, já a página está no cliente e o PHP está no servidor, são coisas completamente separadas, usando outra tecnologia. O fim do *script* que gera a página ou faz alguma outra coisa certamente chama o destrutor se nada catastrófico não acontecer antes.

Se o *script* for chamado novamente todo ambiente de memória do anterior não existe mais e tudo será criado de novo. E esse é o motivo que o destrutor não faz muita diferença em PHP, ainda que conceitualmente ele sempre deveria existir.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Legal a explicação Maniero, bem explicativa. Deixe-me fazer uma outra pergunta nesse mesmo gancho. Os métodos _destruct() das classes que estão sendo usadas em certo Script são executados quando esse Script é finalizado com die() ou, em caso de CLI, quando o comando é abortado?

Comment: Quando o *script* é terminado normalmente sim, mas se ele for encerrado por fora não é chamado. O `die()` encerra normalmente, só não dá pra garantir a ordem que os métodos serão executados.

Answer (score 3):

> No PHP, não há um Garbage Collector, e sim os métodos destrutores

Acho que está equivocado. [PHP: Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)

> Onde e quando usar o método destrutor?

O conceito do destruct é igual a linguagem C++:

> The destructor method will be called **as soon as there are no other references to a particular object**, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

Você não usa diretamente o método `__destruct` e sim o PHP utilizará ele automaticamente assim que não houver mais nenhuma referência ao objeto.

Você pode utilizar o método `__destruct` quando há a necessidade de realizar alguma operação (de forma automática) somente quando o objeto não será mais utilizado. Por exemplo, liberar algum *resource* ou liberar objetos que estejam associados ao seu objeto.

O exemplo mais comum é com conexões com o banco de dados:

```
class Connection {

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->pdo = new PDO(/** connection data **/);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
         //PDO se desconecta automaticamente quando não houver mais referências ao objeto
         //Ou seja, internamente utiliza o método __destruct
         $this->pdo = null;
    }
}
```

Você pode interpretar que PDO também utiliza o método `__destruct`, pois, uma vez que não houver mais referências ao objeto, a conexão com o banco de dados 
será fechada.

O link abaixo pode lhe dar mais alguma ideia de como funciona o garbage collector e as referências do PHP:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348781/object-not-being-destroyed-until-end-of-the-script-if-it-registers-spl-autoload/41462603#41462603

> O método destrutor é executado automaticamente quando a página é fechada?

O método é executado sempre que o objeto não possuir mais referências ou script PHP terminar a sua execução. Ou seja, quando o seu site terminou de carregar por completo, o método `__destruct` já foi executado pelo PHP. O métodos serão executados mesmo que o script seja interrompido utilizando as funções `exit`/`die`. Somente não serão executados por alguma falha na execução ou se a função `exit`/`die` for chamada dentro de um método `__destruct`.

> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.

Diferente de Java e .NET, que existe uma aplicação rodando em um servidor, o PHP não possui uma aplicação que esteja sempre rodando. A aplicação do PHP é criada no momento em que uma requisição é recebida. A aplicação executa todo o seu script (conforme a requisição) e, então, após toda a execução e output, a aplicação é destruída. Por isso, o método `__destruct` sempre será executado.

> Se eu dar F5 na página, o objeto antigo será substituído por um novo ou os dois vão se manter na memória?

Conforme a explicação sobre a aplicação, seus objetos sempre serão destruídos e novos serão criados. Essa é uma particularidade da arquitetura do PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor